# Form submit Alert OK

Tags: javascript, forms, safari, alert, form-submit

Hi I want the form I'm making to submit but not before the users press ENTER key without accepting terms and conditions.

I already made that but in Safari when the user press ENTER, the alert appears, you press OK and the form submits. That's what I want to fix. Thanks

```
<script>
    function alerta(e)
    {               
        var unicode
        if (e.charCode)
        {unicode=e.charCode;}
        else
        {unicode=e.keyCode;}

        if (unicode == 13){
            alert("alert message");
        }
    }
</script>

<form method="post" action="..php" onkeypress="alerta(event)">
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onsubmit attribute on form, and return false, if checkbox not checked.
Or, if you have popup dialog - onsubmit should return false, and pressing "accept" button in dialog trigger form.submit()